# Little issue with 'this' (invalid use of 'this' in a non-member function)

Tags: c++, qt

When I have solved this I am finally done with my prog :D As always, a model of the problem is below. I get the `invalid use of 'this' in a non-member function` error. It seems to me I have done everything correctly: I have moved the class outside the `main` function and I have also not forgotten the `Q_OBJECT` macro... Could anybody please help me here and please mind that I am new to OOP. Thank you!

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>


class MyObject : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

   public:
   QTextEdit text;
   QString a;

   public slots:
   void onClicked() {
      text.setText(a);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QWidget mw;
  mw.setWindowTitle("Main Window");
  mw.resize(400, 400);
  mw.show();

    QLabel label ("Enter something:", &mw);
    label.setAlignment(Qt::AlignHCenter);
    label.show();

    QLineEdit line (&mw);
    line.show();

    QString a = line.text();

    QTextEdit text (&mw);
    text.show();

    QPushButton btn ("Convert", &mw);
    QObject::connect(
      &btn,
      SIGNAL(clicked()),
      this,                 /* the compiler keeps complaining... */
      SLOT(onClicked()));
    btn.show();

  QVBoxLayout layout_mw;

  layout_mw.addWidget(&label);
  layout_mw.addWidget(&line);
  layout_mw.addWidget(&btn);
  layout_mw.addWidget(&text);

  mw.setLayout(&layout_mw);

  return app.exec();

}
```

Comment: what is `this` supposed to be ? As your compiler correctly tells you, you can only use `this` inside member functions in which case it is a pointer to the instance, but what should `this` in `main` be?

Comment: Create a `MyObject` object before `QObject::connect`:  `MyObject obj;` and then change `QObject::connect(
      &btn,
      SIGNAL(clicked()),
      this,                 /* the compiler keeps complaining... */
      SLOT(onClicked()));` to `QObject::connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, &obj, &MyObject::onClicked)`

Comment: You wanted to invoke `onClicked` on your `MyObject` instance instead of a non-existant "this"

Comment: Or save yourself the trouble and use modern Qt: `QObject::connect(&btn, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]() { text.setText(line.text()); });`

Comment: @Botje I am using Qt 4.

Comment: Qt4 was last released in 2011 and has been unsupported since 2015. Why would you learn it or use it today over Qt5?

Comment: because Qt 5 has plenty of troubles with encoding and I'm using UTF-8 throughout the whole program.

Comment: Uh .. I'm using UTF-8 in a large Qt5 application just fine. If that is your reason for going with Qt4 I would strongly recommend you post about those "encoding troubles".

Comment: Then how do you manage to write the whole app using UTF-8? And apply a method to the **whole** program, not to single QStrings? Just come and share it. I  guess your method is simple when you tell you make it "just fine"? The issue is not worth a new post, just tell me what the method is. In Qt 4, I use `QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");` and then `QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(codec);` and that's **all**. What is now your method in Qt 5?

Comment: In Qt 5.11 at least, `QString::QString(const char *)` treats its input as UTF-8. For conversion TO `const char *` you need an explicit `qUtf8Printable(str)` call, yes. But that is also a good reminder that you're taking a pointer to something that is not meant to survive past the current invocation. So your "encoding troubles" are really only in one direction and not (in my opinion) worth ignoring Qt5 for. Apologies if you feel attacked, this was not clear from your post (or comments).

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `this` outside a non-static member function.

It seems you want to connect the `clicked()` signal to the `onClicked()` function on an instance of `MyObject`. That means you need to first of all create an instance of the `MyObject` class. Then use a pointer to that object as the receiver of the signal:

```
MyObject my_object;

QObject::connect(
  &btn,
  SIGNAL(clicked()),
  &my_object,
  SLOT(onClicked()));
```

Be careful though, because the member variables in `MyObject` have *nothing* related with the local variables with the same name in the `main` function.

From my example code above, `my_object.text` is a totally different variable from `text`. The same with `my_object.a` and `a`, of course.

As shown [in a comment to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55102300/little-issue-with-this-invalid-use-of-this-in-a-non-member-function#comment96947614_55102300), there are better ways to do what you want, without the need to create the `MyObject` class.

Comment: Thank you, but I've just tried what you and @eyllanesc and @Xplatforms told me to do (as it is pretty much the same thing) and what I've got is: `undefined reference to vtable for MyObject`. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: @val Move your `MyObject` definition to its own .h/.cpp files, or include "main.moc" at the end of your `main.cpp` and run `qmake` and then rebuild your project.

Comment: @thuga Thank you! I'm doing the latter as I'm using only one .cpp file. I write `#include "sample.moc"` as the name of my file is sample.cpp. I receive a large amount of errors. Maybe I should use some macro before including? Could you please tell me what exactly I am to do... thanks!